# Query with selectionArgs doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have below code, when I use it I get ? instead of selectionArgs. Why does it happen?

```
String enStr = "en", deStr= "de";
String[] projection = {
        _id,
        en_word,
        de_word};

String selection = "translate_id = ?" + " AND "
                + "en_id = ?" + " AND "
                + "de_id = ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf("1"), "en", "de" };

return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
        currentUri,
        projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
        selection,              // No selection clause
        selectionArgs,          // No selection arguments
        null);                  // Default sort order
```

In result I get this query (see ? instead of selectionArgs):

```
SELECT
_id, en_word, de_word
from
translate, en, de
WHERE
translate_id = 1 AND en_id = ? AND de_id = ?;
```

If I use this code, I get a normal query (that shows me the content of the tables). I have just changed selectionArgs with one block selection.

```
String enStr = "en", deStr= "de";
String selection = "translate_id = 1" + " AND "
                + "en_id = " + enStr + " AND "
                + "de_id = ? " + deStr;

return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
        currentUri,
        projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
        selection,              // No selection clause
        null,          // No selection arguments
        null);                  // Default sort order

SELECT
_id, en_word, de_word
from
translate, en, de
WHERE
translate_id = 1 AND en_id = "en" AND de_id = "de";
```

So, why everything works in a second case and doesn't work in a first case. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What does "works" and "doesn't work" mean to you? The first code snippet is ok, the SQL in the second is syntactically broken.

Comment: In first case I get 0 results and in the second case actually I get results?!